# Sony QX1 error: "Not available now"

Tags: python, flask, sony, sony-camera-api

I have recently worked on a web app with Sony QX1. Basically, the web app should be able to change the mode of camera, start/stop shooting, take picture, playback, and etc. For the server side, I am using flask (a template of python)

Everything works fine (I can change the exposure mode, or get the exposure mode) until I change to shooting mode and start shooting movie. It keep giving me the error:

```
{u'id': 1, u'error': [1, u'Not Available Now']}
```

**I am wondering if other functions can't be used if the camera is in shooting mode.**

This confused me for a couple weeks, and I can't find any answer online.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are two camera modes.  Contents Transfer and Remote Shooting.  This is set using the setCameraFunction command.  To change camera settings, take pictures you need to be in Remote Shooting mode. To transfer files and delete files you need to be in Contents Transfer mode.